# Show child as parent in model - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 4.1.4

In that I have a single Model:

```
class FormQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :form_parent_question, :foreign_key => 'form_parent_question_id', :class_name => 'FormQuestion'
  has_one :form_child_question, :foreign_key => 'form_parent_question_id', 

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :form_child_question


end
```

So as you can see, there is a parent and child question.

When I do FormQuestion.all.to_json, then the child question comes inside the parent question on render.

Is there a way so that all questions come as a array ?

Current Response

```
{"form_questions":[
  {
    "id":1,
    "form_child_question": {
      "id":2,
      "form_child_question": null
    }
  }
]}
```

The response I want to achieve but not able to:

```
{"form_questions":[
  {
    "id":1,
    "form_parent_question_id": null
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "form_parent_question_id": 1
  },
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this

```
FormQuestion.all.map{|f| {id: f.id, form_parent_question_id: f.form_parent_question_id } }
```

This will give you the result you expect.

You can use serializers also if you are building apis. Gem you can use is [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)

Comment: Already using serializers. But they weren't working properly. I am using the same gem you mentioned.

Comment: Can you tell me the version of rails and version of active_model_serializer you are using

Comment: 0.9.5 for active model serializer and 4.1.4 for rails

Comment: Without serialiser are you able to do like i shown in top